# Persistent store handling

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am working on email kind of application on Blackberry.
I want to store all the mails in persistent store.
Also the list of contacts needs to be stored.

How do I manipulate such kind of functionality using persistet store?

How do I store data?

Can multiple messages are saved ?

And how to acccess them correctly and display on screen?

I have never worked on persistent store before, 
please help.

Comment: Platform? Programming language?

Comment: what a cruel people. Author, you should really take a time composing question messages on stackoverflow. That means less emotions, more information, well structured, with data structure code, with any related code. It's not only for your help, someone else may need same answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no indexing in persistent storage.
You can save and retrieve arrays of Persistable objects.
On example, Contact Persistable:

```
public class Contact implements Persistable{
    int mId; String mAdress; String mName;    
    public Contact( int id, String adress, String name ){
        mId = id; mAdress = adress; mName = name;
    }    
}
```

Mail Persistable:

```
public class Mail implements Persistable{
    String mMessage = null; int mSenderId = -1; int[] mReceiverIdList = null;    
    public Mail(String message, int senderId, int[] receiverIdList){
        mMessage = message; mSenderId = senderId; 
        mReceiverIdList = receiverIdList;
    }
}
```

Some Helper class:

```
public class PersistentStoreHelper{
    static PersistentObject contactStore = PersistentStore
            .getPersistentObject( 0xf140775afcb94f90L );
    static PersistentObject mailStore = PersistentStore
    .getPersistentObject( 0xd43b0423228ff7c0L );
    public static void saveContacts( Contact[] contacts ){
        saveObject( contactStore, contacts );
    }
    public static void saveMails( Mail[] mails ){
        saveObject( mailStore, mails );
    }
    public static Contact[] retrieveContacts(){
        return ( Contact[] )retrieveObject( contactStore );
    }
    public static Mail[] retrieveMails(){
        return ( Mail[] )retrieveObject( mailStore );
    }
    public static void saveObject( PersistentObject store, Object object ){
        synchronized( store ){
            store.setContents( object );
            store.commit();
        }
    }
    public static Object retrieveObject( PersistentObject store ){
        Object result = null;
        synchronized( store ){
            result = store.getContents();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And sample of using:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener{
    ButtonField mBtnInit = null;
    BasicEditField mInputSenderId = null;
    BasicEditField mInputReceiverId = null;
    ButtonField mBtnSearch = null;
    VerticalFieldManager mMailsList = null;
    public Scr(){
        mBtnInit = new ButtonField( "Init Persistenet Storage", 
            ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK );
        mBtnInit.setChangeListener( this );
        add( mBtnInit );
        mInputSenderId = new BasicEditField( "sender id:", "43" );
        add( mInputSenderId );
        mInputReceiverId = new BasicEditField( "receiver id:", "12" );
        add( mInputReceiverId );
        mBtnSearch = new ButtonField( "Search", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK );
        mBtnSearch.setChangeListener( this );
        add( mBtnSearch );
        mMailsList = new VerticalFieldManager();
        add( mMailsList );
    }
    public Vector getMailByIds( int senderId, int recepientId ){
        Vector result = new Vector();
        Mail[] mails = PersistentStoreHelper.retrieveMails();
        for( int i = 0; i < mails.length; i++ )
            if( mails[ i ].mSenderId == senderId ){
                int[] receiverIdList = mails[ i ].mReceiverIdList;
                for( int j = 0; j < receiverIdList.length; j++ )
                    if( recepientId == receiverIdList[ j ] )
                        result.addElement( mails[ i ] );
            }
        return result;
    }
    public void initPersistentStorage(){
        // create 100 contacts and save them
        Contact[] contacts = new Contact[ 100 ];
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){
            String name = "name" + String.valueOf( i );
            String adress = name + "@mail.com";
            contacts[ i ] = new Contact( i, adress, name );
        }
        PersistentStoreHelper.saveContacts( contacts );
        // create messages from each to every contact and save them
        Mail[] mails = new Mail[ 10000 - 100 ];
        int k = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < 100; j++ )
                if( i != j ){
                    Mail mail = new Mail( "Hello!", contacts[ i ].mId, 
                        new int[]{ contacts[ j ].mId } );
                    mails[ k ] = mail;
                    k++;
                }
        PersistentStoreHelper.saveMails( mails );        
    }
    public void fieldChanged( Field field, int context ){
        if( field == mBtnInit )
            initPersistentStorage();
        else if( field == mBtnSearch ){
            mMailsList.deleteAll();
            int senderId = Integer.parseInt( mInputSenderId.getText() );
            int receiverId = Integer.parseInt( mInputReceiverId.getText() );
            Contact[] contacts = PersistentStoreHelper.retrieveContacts();
            Vector result = getMailByIds( senderId, receiverId );
            for( int i = 0, cnt = result.size(); i < cnt; i++ )
            {
                Mail mail = ( Mail )result.elementAt( i );
                String from = "From: " + contacts[ mail.mSenderId ].mName 
                        + " <" + contacts[ mail.mSenderId ].mAdress + ">";
                String to = "To: ";
                for( int j = 0; j < mail.mReceiverIdList.length; j++ )
                {
                    int id = mail.mReceiverIdList[ j ];
                    to += contacts[ id ].mName + " <" 
                        + contacts[ id ].mAdress + ">; ";
                }
                to = to.substring( 0, to.length() - 2 );
                String msg = "Message: " + mail.mMessage;
                mMailsList.add( new LabelField( from ) );
                mMailsList.add( new LabelField( to ) );
                mMailsList.add( new LabelField( msg ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read [BlackBerry Java Application - Core - Development Guide - Persistent Storage](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/9137/Persistent_data_storage_509562_11.jsp)
Also you can read [riccomini - code blackberry persistent store](http://www.riccomini.name/Topics/Mobile/BlackBerry/BlackBerryPersistentStore/)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer...
How do I store the data similar to storage in relational database?
How can I have indexes on the data? I am not getting it...